# Word for someone that believes he deserves everything he wants

Tags: single-word-requests

What's the word for someone that believes he deserves everything he wants?

I'm thinking "spoiled" or "entitled", but I'm sure there's a more accurate word out there.

**EDIT:**

"what do I have against entitled?" I'm thinking about it, and it is actually a perfect word, but I realized I'm not looking for an *adjective* but a *noun*. As in:

"I'm tired of the ***something-ness of these people", which I know can be rephrased as "I'm tired of these entitled people", but I wanted some variety... 
"sense of entitlement", maybe? but in just one word... I feel there should be a word for it, (just "entitlement", then?) or maybe I'm being too pushy.

Comment: What reservations do you have for *entitled*?

Answer (score 1):

I would call such a person a **narcissist.**

> easily angered, especially when they don't receive the attention they consider their birthright.

[Narcissism (from Psychology Today)](https://www.psychologytoday.com/basics/narcissism)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few that could be just shy of the exact meaning, and if you're open to combinations, you could have more options

*egocentric*: This is more like someone who is concerned with getting only what he wants, without regard for anyone else.

*poise*: If she is confident she deserves everything she wants, then she could be said to have a *certain* poise (there are several words that could work here: stately, reclined, unconcerned).

*airy*: You could use this for tone to depict the he does not worry because he knows he deserves everything.

Answer (score 1):

I think entitlement is the most accurate word.

"belief that one is deserving of or entitled to certain privileges"

"celebrities who have an arrogant sense of entitlement"

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/entitlement

A synonym would be presumptuousness. But entitlement is easier to spell. :)